# Unable to capture the password in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have written a simple program to capture the password from the command using `getpass`, but the program is hanging in

I would like to grab the password and display it.

```
import getpass


class PasswordEnter:

    def enterPassword(self):
        while True:
            print("--------------")
            password = getpass.getpass(prompt='Enter Password: ', stream=None)
            if not password:
                continue
            else:
                print("Actual Password : ", password)
                break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = PasswordEnter();
    test.enterPassword()
```

Comment: I tried running it on a window machine in PowerShell and it works fine. May be some issue with pycharm. Try to run it in a shell.

Comment: [Stop writing classes](https://youtu.be/o9pEzgHorH0)

Comment: It is working fine in windows console, but it is not working in Pycharm.

Comment: in pycharm you can't take password in the python interpreter, change configuration and run the code in python konsole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pycharm does not directly allow to capture password. We have to tell Pycharm to behave like a terminal. Here are the steps below.

1. Press two times  **Shift** key
2. Write **Edit Configurations** .
3. Select "**Edit Configuration**" and select your program.
4. Select the check box "**Emulate terminal in output console**".
5. Apply and then press OK. Now run the program.

Comment: Thanks. Works with pycharm pro 2019.3 on ubuntu 18.